# Installing Vmware horizon client using Wine

Tags: fedora, vmware, wine, winetricks

I am trying to install VMware Horizon client 5.4.3 using Wine in my Fedora 29 system. When I am opening with the .exe file with Wine its opening and promoting to install `.Net 4.5` version after I press `Install` it's exiting automatically from the installation process. Below is the output in the terminal. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
[sdutta@sandysdora ~]$ wine ./Downloads/VMware-Horizon-Client-5.4.3-16346110.exe 
0009:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
0009:fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
0009:fixme:advapi:DecryptFileW (L"C:\\users\\sdutta\\Temp\\{A7221785-FAF5-4BF2-9CEF-C069D3A817CB}\\", 00000000): stub
002b:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
002b:fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
002b:fixme:advapi:DecryptFileW (L"C:\\users\\sdutta\\Temp\\{27C0B175-6D01-4CE7-AFC6-EC68B0B94459}\\", 00000000): stub
002b:fixme:mscoree:metahostpolicy_GetRequestedRuntime ignoring config file stream
002b:fixme:mscoree:metahostpolicy_GetRequestedRuntime ignoring config flags
002b:fixme:advapi:DecryptFileW (L"C:\\users\\sdutta\\Temp\\{27C0B175-6D01-4CE7-AFC6-EC68B0B94459}\\", 00000000): stub
002b:fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
0030:fixme:heap:RtlSetHeapInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0 stub
0030:fixme:ntdll:NtQueryInformationToken QueryInformationToken( ..., TokenElevation, ...) semi-stub
0030:fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0x33f578,-1,(nil),(nil),6,2,(nil),12288,(nil)) - stub!
0030:fixme:wuapi:automatic_updates_Pause 
0030:fixme:sfc:SRSetRestorePointW 0x33f440 0x33f650
0030:fixme:wuapi:automatic_updates_Resume 
0030:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fe24 (nil)): stub
002b:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fe24 (nil)): stub
0009:fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33fe24 (nil)): stub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [WineTricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks) to install .Net 4.5. If the application still doesn't install or work afterwards then most likely you're out of luck and this application can't work under Wine.

Lastly, Fedora 29 has long been unsupported (since 2019-11-26) and features a very outdated Wine release. I strongly recommend upgrading to Fedora 32.